# How to use half precision in renderscript?

Tags: android, renderscript, android-renderscript

I use the following code to transfer an array of float numbers to a renderscript kernel:

```
 float[] bufName = new float[3];
 bufName [0] = 255;
 bufName [1] = 255;
 bufName [2] = 0;

 Allocation alloc1 = Allocation.createSized(mRs, Element.F32(mRs), 3);
 alloc1.copy1DRangeFrom(0, 3, mtmd);
 ScriptC_foo foo = new ScriptC_foo(mRs);
 foo.set_gIn(alloc1);
```

And I have defined `gIn` in the `foo.rs` file as follows:

```
rs_allocation gIn;
```

I would like to work with 16 bit floating point numbers. I know that I should change the allocation creation to this:

```
 Allocation alloc1 = Allocation.createSized(mRs, Element.F16(mRs), 3);
```

However, I cannot find a solution for copying the bufName array to the allocation. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java does not define half-precision floats, so you'll have to do your own manipulation to get this to work.  If you use `Float.valueOf(f).shortValue()` (where `f` is the specific flow you'd like to represent as half-precision).  This should properly cast down the `float` to the new bit size.  Then create an `Allocation` of `Element.F16` size.  You should be able to copy an array of `short` values down to RenderScript to do the work.

Comment: Thanks for your response. `Float.valueOf(f).shortValue()` converts the numbers to integer (short) numbers. I want to keep the fractional part.

Comment: It was admittedly a long shot. You may be able to use one of the `Float` methods to convert to int bits, then scale down to short bits.

Comment: You might be able to copy half-floats to the allocation using the native RenderScript api.